# Geolocation API coordinates incorrect for CDMA cellid

Tags: android, api, geolocation, cellid, cdma

I work for a small cellular carrier in Michigan. Our customer's Android phones are receiving inaccurate coordinates when served by a particular cellID. Can we provide Google with updated coordinate information for this cellID?

```
brock@ws1:~# cat celldata.json 
{
 "homeMobileCountryCode": 310,
 "homeMobileNetworkCode": 1350,
 "radioType": "cdma",
 "carrier": "Thumb Cell",
 "cellTowers": [
  {
   "cellId": 16435,
   "locationAreaCode": 0,
   "mobileCountryCode": 310,
   "mobileNetworkCode": 1350,
   "age": 0,
   "signalStrength": -80
  }
 ]
}
brock@ws1:~# curl -d @celldata.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=hidden"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Fri, 09 May 2014 14:51:53 GMT
ETag: "tWi4Lxc9BOVIuoBFIxSkFtb7KLg/mcMcHq7UHbH_KtCJEZ7JurKLA7k"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
 "location": {
  "lat": 44.0921216,
  "lng": -83.5834574
 },
 "accuracy": 3791.0
}

brock@ws1:~#
```